# What needs to be done in this codesandbox error?

Tags: codesandbox

On opening any of my html/css/js/react files, the codesandbox is not opening the relevant files and instead it is showing like this :

[image]

"Could not load the editor. It is likely your previous session got stale and you need to refresh again to get the latest version of the Editor"

I tried a lot on google but could not find one.

Comment: I would ask this to CodeSandbox support. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Application tab in the developer tools and do the following -

1. Un-register all service workers
2. Clear Local storage
3. Clear Session storage
4. Delete all IndexedDB databases.
5. Clear all cookies
6. Delete all Cache storages.

Then, reload the page and login again. Issue will be solved.